# Printing Displayed URL Image with Handlebarsjs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, handlebars.js, woocommerce-rest-api

Ok so I have this template receipt file that I'm working on. I use this code to display an image on the webpage preview of the receipt:

```
<div class="barcode"><img class="barcode" src='https://www.example.com/?wc_barcode={{meta_data.[1].[value]}}'/></br>{{meta_data.[1].[value]}}</div>
```

What the image link ends up looking like in html on the preview page is:

```
 https://www.example.com/?wc_barcode=6094644a91bc7
```

When you try to download the image it's an unnamed .png. It does not exist on my server and is generated by the link on the fly. It's Woocommerce Order Barcodes plugin from Woocommerce. Either way, the image shows perfectly fine in the preview but when I go to print the receipt the image disappears. Can someone help me understand what might be going on and what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what was done, but the developer customized the plugin to work the way I was using it so if someone else tries to use it like I am they will not have a problem either as the plugin is specifically designed to be embedded into different files and templates.

The Plugin is called Digital Barcodes by UKRSolution. Figured since they provided such great support and even extended plugin functionality due to not seeing someone using it in the manner I was, that I would let anyone interested or looking for this type of solution know.